# Equivalent of React Native iOS '-(void)startObserving' in Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, events

I have an iOS native module in my React Native app which ensures that events fired before JS starts listening are delivered:

```objectivec
-(void)startObserving {
  hasListeners = YES;
  if ([delayedEvents count] > 0) {
    [self sendEventWithName:@"delayedEvents" body:delayedEvents];
    [delayedEvents removeAllObjects];
  }
}

-(void)stopObserving {
  hasListeners = NO;
}

-(void)sendOrQueueEventWithName:(NSString *)name data:(NSDictionary *)data {
  if (hasListeners) {
    [self sendEventWithName:name body:data];
  } else {
    NSDictionary *event = @{
      @"name": name,
      @"data": data,
    };
    [delayedEvents addObject:event];
  }
}
```

Code that triggers events then calls `sendOrQueueEventWithName` in lieu of `sendEventWithName`, and React Native JS listens for the `delayedEvents` event.

What are the options for achieving the same thing in an Android native module?

I am currently using a combination of RCTDeviceEventEmitter events for when the app is running and passing initial props to the app by overriding ReactActivityDelegate `getLaunchOptions()` for when it isn't, but in the situation where the app is closed using the home button and subsequently destroyed by the system (reproduce using the "don't keep activities" developer option), `onCreate()` is called with a stale event and `onNewIntent()` is called with the updated event, but only after `getLaunchOptions()` is called, so the app launches with a stale event. I have `android:launchMode="singleTask"` on my main activity and don't believe I can change this without causing other issues.

```java
public static class CustomReactActivityDelegate extends ReactActivityDelegate {
    private Bundle initialProps = null;
    private final ReactActivity activity;

    public CustomReactActivityDelegate(ReactActivity activity, String mainComponentName) {
        super(activity, mainComponentName);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bundle = activity.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("event")) {
            Bundle event = bundle.getBundle("event");
            initialProps = new Bundle();
            initialProps.putBundle("event", event);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("event")) {
            Bundle event = bundle.getBundle("event");
            initialProps = new Bundle();
            initialProps.putBundle("event", event);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
        return initialProps;
    }
}
```